# Removing commas in the standard return value of toLocaleString

Tags: javascript

I've searched the web and I only found how to add commas between number, but I want to do a reverse which is removing the commas in number.

Here is my JavaScript Code

```
const format = (num, decimals) => num.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});

console.log(format(3460));
```

It returns, 3,460.00. I want it to return 3460.00 only.

Comment: Are you sure you even want to use `toLocaleString`?

Comment: Is there any alternative I can use?

Comment: What is your actual goal?

Comment: Just to format numbers into to decimal places. toFixed() failed to round sometime for example in 1.005 value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `toLocaleString`, it has a [`useGrouping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) option you can set to false:

```js
const format = (num, decimals) => num.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: false
});

console.log(format(3460));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const format = (num, decimals) => num.toLocaleString('en-US', {
minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
maximumFractionDigits: 2,
}).split(",").join("");

console.log(format(3460));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN : 
**The toLocaleString() method returns a string with a language-sensitive representation of this number.**

I would do following:

```
 const parseFloatToFixedPlaces =  (x,decimalPlaces) => {
  if(decimalPlaces === 'undefined')
    {
       decimalPlaces = 0
    }
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(decimalPlaces);
}
```